# Qt proper connect() calling

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a problem regarding `connect()` method, non of these below calls work:

```
connect(tutorial->back, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(exit_button_clicked()));
connect(tutorial->back, &QPushButton::clicked(), this, &MyMainWindow::exit_button_clicked());
```

The first one does not call `exit_button_clicked()` and the second one tells me that `clicked()` must be static(in Clion) and does not compile .`back` is an `QPushButton` and `tutorial` is an custom `QWidget` class. It is important to implement this method by calling custom function (for further use). Can anyone show me the right way to implement this??

## UPDATE:

the problem was with my `CMakeLists.txt`, I added `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` and `Q_Object` macro to my classes and it works fine now.

Comment: Is your `exit_button_clicked()` declared as slot in your header file?

Comment: "Can anyone show me the right way to implement this??" The Qt documentation has about a trazillion of that.

Comment: @Slyps yes i know that (I have read it a hundred times) but the first approach must generate correct answer, there is nothing wrong with it in my opinion. I just can't figure out why it does not work

Comment: @kefir500 yes, this is my implementation: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11825153/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume, your `exit_button_clicked()` is declared as a private or public function (not as a slot). Qt custom signals and slots have to be declared in a proper way. For example, you have your class Tutorial:

```
class Tutorial : QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    // Your class members go here.
    // Add this slot declaration:
    private slots:
        void exit_button_clicked();
}
```

(Note the `slots` keyword next to the `private`).

Slots can also be public or protected, as you wish.

Comment: Your class lacks `Q_OBJECT` macro

Comment: yes, I have deleted it, cause it gives me compile error: `undefined reference to 'vtable for MyMenu'`

Comment: ok, my `CMakeLists.txt` file was the problem, i added `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` and it works fine now, thank you for your response :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, there must be something wrong with your `exit_button_clicked()` slot. It should be a simple member function with `slots` specifier taking `void` and returning `void` in a class with `Q_OBJECT` macro. If the connection fails, it writes the error at run-time to the console (probably through `qDebug()`).

In the second case, it's clear that you have extra `()` after the function names. Taking the addresses of the functions looks like this:

```
connect(tutorial->back, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyMainWindow::exit_button_clicked);
```

`&QPushButton::clicked()` tries to call the function and take an address of a return value, which of course fails at compile-time, because `QPushButton::clicked` is not `static`.

I hope this clarifies it. Looking into documentation wouldn't do any harm neighter.

Comment: thank you for your response, but it still does not work (second method), it gives me compile errors that I don't understand: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11825150/) and about the first one this is the way I implement it: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11825153/)

Comment: my `CMakeLists.txt` file was the problem, i added `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` and it works fine now (both methods), thank you for your response :-)